# Symfony2 - What is the point of specifying your own route names?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Currently learning Symfony. Just wondering about route names, which the book doesn't really seem to say in advance what they are for.

As I understand it, @Route annotations are given a default name based on the bundle, controller and action name. So what's the point in specifying your own route names?

- Is it good practice to either leave all routes to have a default name?
- Is it better practice to specify your own name for every route?
- What if two routes have the same name?
- How am I expected to know if I'm using a route name which is already taken, perhaps in another bundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Route names are important because your code will often need to build url's.  The route name is how you specify which url to construct.  Names are also handy for listeners (such as authentication) which process specific url's.

1. Annotation generated default names are fine but tend to be long and could change on you.
2. Yes, I would give every route a custom name for convenience and readability.  Plus, I don't use annotations.  To me at least, storing routes in a central file make the code easier to maintain.  It avoids the need to search through multiple controller files trying to determine which code handles which request.
3. Routes with the same name will replace any previously loaded route.  It's useful if you wish to override a route from a third party bundle.
4. Namespace your route by using some form of your bundle name as a prefix.

Comment: If Symfony names routes by default as bundle_controller_action why wouldn't that work well? That's exactly the sort of route naming-convention I would come with probably, to ensure routes in my app have unique, logical names. What better convention would you suggest?

Comment: I updated my answer.  I confess I did not read your original question close enough.  Mostly because I don't use annotations.  Plus, I tend to re factor my controllers which would cause the route names to change.  But if the default names work for you then use them.

Comment: there's one thing to be aware of when depending on auto generated names - if this naming convention will change some day you will have to change all places that depend on this. When you give your name manually you're independend of conventions.